# Access Secrets like password from AWS Batch job using secret store other than Secret Manager( like Vault, Kubernetes secrets)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-batch, kubernetes-secrets, vault

I am trying to figure out is there a way to access secrets like db password from AWS Batch job using Vault/ K8S secrets. The option to use Secret Manager provided by AWS is there, but as per my company policy we are using vault across the projects. AWS batch documentation does not have any documentation on options to store secrets other than Secret Manager.
Can anyone help me if using vault/ k8s secret is an option with AWS Batch.

Comment: I don't see why it would be any different from using it in any other program. What problems are you running into?

Comment: I need to access in code as well as in EC2 startup user script( to access docker private registry password ). In code I can handle by hitting vault API but in EC2 script I am not sure how to handle. It is required in EC2 script because AWS batch by default provide connectivity with ECR only but we are using organizational private docker registry.

Comment: You may need to run a program that runs at EC2 startup time. Since Batch starts EC2 instances as-needed, this might mean that you download the program as part of the EC2 startup script. Or create an AMI that includes it already installed.

Comment: Can I use vault in that script that will run as part of startup script of EC2? By curl or some other way?